# How to match interrogation and exclamation marks in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Proper Spanish writing requires to have opening and closing marks for interrogation and exclamation. Eg: `¡Qué buena página!`, `¿Cómo cambiar emacs?`.

I would like to have the same behavior as parentheses matching: highlight the pair or show that one is mismatched.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you try http://thinkinghard.com/spanish/spanish-emacs.html ?

Comment: One method would be to use font-lock to define a single character (e.g., interrogation / exclamation up or down) in one color -- e.g., font-lock-warning-face.  When a match is found, the beginning / ending characters could change to a matching color or simply return to the standard color default for text foreground.  This method would not require syntax entry modification.  You could get fancy and highlight everything after or before an unmatched character.

Comment: My impression is that spanish-mode is just to write spanish characters, which I get done with an International English Keyboard layout. @user1034749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory to get matches, for example between  "<" and ">"
you should write:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?< "(>")
(modify-syntax-entry ?> ")<")
```

But this is not work for all unicode symbols,
see http://projects.haskell.org/pipermail/haskellmode-emacs/2011-July/000107.html

Comment: Did anyone file an Emacs bug for this problem of insufficient Unicode support by syntax tables? If so, please mention the bug # here (with a link). If not, *please file a bug* (you can point to the thread you link to above): `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: **This should be the correct answer**, IMO - the right way to do it. Have you actually tried this with the OP's characters? (Maybe it works in this case.)

Comment: It does works! I did `(modify-syntax-entry ?¿ "(?")
(modify-syntax-entry ?? ")¿")
(modify-syntax-entry ?¡ "(!")
(modify-syntax-entry ?! ")¡")
`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first *rough* draft of the idea mentioned in my comment above -- it contemplates the user is in `text-mode`:

```
(defun my-custom-keywords ()

  (font-lock-add-keywords nil (list

    (list "\\(¡\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)\\(!\\)"
      '(1 font-lock-keyword-face t)
      '(2 'default t)
      '(4 font-lock-keyword-face t))

    (list "\\(¿\\)\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)+?\\)\\([?]\\)"
      '(1 font-lock-keyword-face t)
      '(2 'default t)
      '(4 font-lock-keyword-face t))

    (list "\\(¡\\|!\\|¿\\|[?]\\)"
      '(1 font-lock-warning-face))  )))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-custom-keywords)
```

Comment: This accomplishes a very nice result, which I'm definitively implementing from now on. But it lacks the behavior I already have and expect from parentheses.